# $.ajax() using local plain object does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm creating a plain object first before I use $.ajax. So I can add other key/values to configure the request before loading it:

```
var options =   {
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(msg){
        alert('This works!');
        cfunc(msg);
        delete xmlPool[key];
    }
};


xhr = $.ajax(options);
```

Sadly, no 'This works!' message is displayed... Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Maybe the server is not returning valid JSON and the error handler is called? Or you are not allowed to access the URL.  The syntax itself is certainly correct.

Comment: You have defined the variable `url` somewhere in your code, right?

Comment: What do you see in chrome developer tools?

Comment: @Amit: Why? `contentType` is used to tell server in which format the data is sent by the client. But the OP is not even sending any data to the server. This setting has no impact on the *response*.

Comment: Thank you all, it seemed that sometimes it did work, only sometimes I did not received JSON data, then it got buggy. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth adding an error block to check to see if some error is happening?

```
error: function (e, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: and it should be console.log()

Comment: Thanks this helped me find the problem, seemed it did work only in some occasions I didn't received data in JSON.